# Obfuscating Play 2 web app on dist with Proguard?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt, proguard

How to automatically obfuscate a Play Framework web app when the `play state|dist` command is executed?

The idea is to use [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) to perform Java code obfuscation.

There are plugins for SBT, such as [sbt-proguard](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard) and [xsbt-proguard-plugin](https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin), but I'm not sure if I can integrate them with Play 2 straightforward.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this is possible for Play Framework `2.0.x`, but it can be done from `2.2.0` onwards.

You can follow the steps given [here](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-proguard). All of the steps are pretty straight-forward. However, you'll need to know where the required files are:

- `plugins.sbt` - You can find it in `PLAY_HOME/framework/project/plugins.sbt`
- `build.sbt` - You will find this in your application root folder. This file is available only from Play 2.2.0 onwards.

These steps should be sufficient to integrate the plugin with Play

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I believe it is not that straightforward, since we need to keep configurations and classes names consistency. Any idea on how to solve this? Do we need some -keep rules? Which ones?

Moreover, when I call the dist command, proguard is not used. I tried to use the generated proguard jar in the dist folder, but it did not worked, due to references inconsistencies.

Comment: Are there any clear and straightforward tutorial about this topic?